# Kernel Density Estimation of Hazard rate using R

Tags: survival, simulation, kernel-smoothing, hazard

How can we estimate the hazard rate using Kernel density estimation? For the time being I am simulating 1000 observations from exponential distribution, then estimate its hazard rate using gaussian kernel. Instead of getting a straight line (y=1) they gives a plot shown below.

```
# rm(list = ls(all=T))    # To remove all objects 
n=1000                  # To fix the number to simulate
set.seed(1)             # 
x=rexp(n,1)             # Simulating from exponential
y=density(x,n=n)        # Density estimation using a function "density"
f=y$y                   # Extracting estimated value for f(x)
F1=ecdf(x)              # Empirical distribution function
F=F1(x)                 # Empirical distribution function for x values
r=which(F==1)           # For removing zeros from denominator
x=x[-r]
f=f[-r]
F=F[-r]
h=f/(1-F)               # Estimating hazard function
plot(h, ylim = c(-1,2)) # plot for hazard rate
abline(h = 1, v = 0, col = "gray60")
```

[image: Plot of hazard rate]

Comment: Maybe [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/muhaz/muhaz.pdf)? See [this google search](https://www.google.no/search?q=hazard+rate+estimation+kernel+density&oq=hazard+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l4.6068j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)  for some interesting hits.

Comment: Please do not include `rm(list=ls())` in code samles here! Somebody just copying&running the code could get angry at you! For now, I commented it out.